# Static Multi Dimensional Arrays ( C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, memory, multidimensional-array, stack

Is memory allocated for multidimensional arrays in C or C++ always contiguous, or is the storage dependent on the compiler? If it is guaranteed to be contiguous is there a standard on it somewhere for reference? For example

```
int x[2][2] = { { 1 , 2 } , { 5 , 10 } } ;
```

Are the integers 1, 2, 5, 10 in sequence in memory ?

Comment: The "multidimensional array" is really a single-dimension array whose elements are themselves arrays.  An array is guaranteed to have no padding and to have its elements in order of their index.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are guaranteed contiguous. What we have here is an array of arrays - each layer of which is contiguous. The inner most arrays we know must be `{1, 2}` and `{5, 10}`, and the outer most array must also be contiguous. Therefore, `{{1,2},{5,10}}` must be 1, 2, 5, 10 sequentially in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Arrays are always allocated in contiguous memory location. It doesn't matter whether its a single or multi dimensional array.